# How to create a custom Routing-Controller method decorator like Authorized

Tags: node.js, typescript

I noticed we were able to create custom param decorators, but I can't seem to find a way to make custom method decorators.

I would like to be able to create my own versions of something similar to `Authroized` decorator that perform some additional checks. I can then compose them together by adding or removing decorators.

For example, a route may look like this:

```
@Authorized()
@SomeCheck()
@SomeOtherCheck()
@Post("/someRoute")
public CompleteOnboarding(){

}

@Authorized()
@SomeCheck()
@ADifferentCheck()
@Post("/someRoute")
public CompleteOnboarding(){

}
```

It seems I can push some fake 'roles' into `Authorized` and have my `authorizationChecker` perform the additional checks based on what '`roles`' are passed in, but this seemed like a bit of a hack and not very extensible so I thought maybe there is another another way.